# xcode "Done Button" GameCenter doesn´t do anything

Tags: xcode

this is my first app including the gamecenter, and i have a little problem with it.
i implemented some code i found in the net that should work. Everything works fine, except for "done button" :(

.m

```
 #import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error == nil)
                NSLog(@"Authentication Successful!");
            else
                NSLog(@"Authentication Failed!");
        }];


-(IBAction)subscore{

    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"lrhseasy"];
    scoreReporter.value = score;
    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Submitting a score failed!");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Submitting succeeded!");
        }
    }];

}
-(IBAction)showLeader{

    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc]init];
    if (leaderboardController != nil) {
        //leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
    }

}


    - (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController {
        NSLog(@"Close leaderboard");
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [viewController.view.superview removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

The last function isn´t called, when the done button is pressed - i don´t get "close leaderboard" in the debug console.

After searching for 3 hours, the only thing i found was
"**Did you add GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate to the list of protocols that this class implements?** " but i do not know what this means or how its done :(

Answer (score 2):

I am having a similar problem but to add GKLeaderBoardViewControllerDelegate to your protocol list do this:

```
@interface YourClass: NSObject <GKLeaderBoardViewControllerDelegate> {

}

@end
```